# move subfolder out of svn 1.7 wc, treat as new wc

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Before WC-NG was implemented in svn 1.7 I could simply drag a subfolder out of its parent and treat it as a completely separate wc. I'm having trouble finding an easy way to do this post-1.7. I can't find anyone else who seems to care about it as much as me, either.

inb4 'just check out a new wc'.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because every versioned folder has an .svn hidden folder inside. This feature was removed in TortoiseSVN 1.7, which only the root directory of your working copy has the .svn folder. This makes your dragged-out subfolder being treated as unversioned by TortoiseSVN.

By the way, dragging the subfolder out of the parent folder could be considered as a bad practice, since you could be jeopardizing working copy integrity with this procedure.

Comment: Pre 1.7 copying and pasting a subfolder complete with .svn was perfectly harmless. "Dragging" tends to suggest a move - agreed that is a slightly odd way of working unless the removal is then reverted.

Comment: You have explained only why the change causes the problematic behavior. Additionally I would argue that this possible jeopardization of wc integrity is an application-centered concern and not a repository-centered one. For some applications it is perfectly reasonable (for instance if the repo is merely a collection of sub modules, to use a git concept), others not.

Comment: @noobish It's been a while since I answered this question, and I confess I don't use SVN anymore, so this solution can be a little bit outdated.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez: completely understood. I myself am not using it either, but I didn't want the unselected answer to go by for another 6 years without addressing why I didn't select it.

Answer (score 0):

Export a subfolder to an outside location. It will make a copy of all versioned files. Then do a checkout from svn source to that folder. Torotoisesvn will version all existing files and add/remove new ones. And the last step. It may happen that someone make changes to a code inside that svn subtree in the period of time between original wc revision and new sub-wc revision. In such case tortoisvn will show as you have modified files back  to original wc revision. You just need to revert all these changes.

It's the only way of doing such sub-wc I know of. For a large code base it saves a lot of network traffic and time.

Comment: The checkout part of this procedure will surely bring down all files in exactly the same way as a fresh checkout to an empty folder. Otherwise, how would tsvn be able to show the modifications to which you refer? In other words while this is a legitimate technique I'm not seeing the network traffic advantage over a clean checkout. Now that svn no longer stores .svn folders in each folder and only in the top level folder tsvn really needs to add an "Export with versioning information" option imho.

Comment: If someone can corroborate the supposition here that a checkout operation over an existing folder will not duplicate network transfer but instead do something like rsync and only transfer changed files, I can accept this answer. But I doubt that is the case, in which case I agree with @StephenKennedy.

What a horrible workaround if this is the only way.